# Angular - Dato de Local Storage (async) para ser tomado luego en Observable

Tags: angular, ionic, local-storage

Implementé un servicio en Angular, Ionic,  que tiene métodos para manejar Local Storage que funciona bien. La cuestión es que todos los métodos que hacen set o get son asíncronos (async) y tengo, en pseudo código, lo siguiente:

```
const elem = getItemLocalStorage('item')
http.post('http://www.......com.ar/...', {elemento: elem})
```

Yo necesito que en el http.post se cargue el dato que traigo del local Storage, pero siempre llega undefined, ya que la función "getItemLocalStorage" se ejecuta por otro hilo, asincrónicamente, entonces cuando carga el dato en el http.post siempre es undefined.

¿Como hago para esperar el dato del local Storage y que recién allí se cargue en la sentencia de abajo?

Gracias

Comment: Conviértelo a promesa, después usas un `await` para esperar a que se resuelva.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Pasar un `callback` cuando la promesa se resuelva:

   ```
   getItemLocalStorage().then(elemento => {
     http.post('http://www.......com.ar/...', {elemento})
   })
   ```
2. Usar `await` para esperar por el resultado

   ```
   const elem = await getItemLocalStorage('item')
   http.post('http://www.......com.ar/...', {elemento: elem})
   ```